# WPF how to set height of empty listview to 0

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I bind the items to ListView, and I found if there is no items in listview the height will be 2.
So I just want to make the height to 0 if the ListView is Empty.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. 
Please try to be more detailed when asking a question: add the relevant code parts - probably the XAML in your case - and explain what did you try to solve the issue. Those details will help others better understand your problem and thus you have a better chance of getting a relevant answer.

Comment: But you might check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154213/how-to-define-empty-datatemplate-for-the-itemscontrol-based-controls-like-listvi) to see a solution that uses a custom template when an ItemsControl is empty.

Comment: consider adding some code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data trigger to achive this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" Height="100" Width="100" Background="HotPink">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MySource.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```